# Finding the bounds of the missing values of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, normal-distribution, numerical-linear-algebra, entropy

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix that we know is positive semi-definite and has missing entries. For example:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&1&x\\
1&x&1
\end{pmatrix}
$

How can I find (preferably analytically, but algorithmically is ok) the values of $x$ that would make this matrix positive semi-definite?

Extra background for the interested: The matrix I am looking at is a covariance matrix, which we know is PSD. I want to find the possible values of $x$ so that, from the possible values, I choose the one that would render the maximum entropy distribution.

Comment: you asked Robert for a general method; Sylvester's Law of Inertia gives a method... If your symmetric matrix is $M,$   you calculate  a square nonsingular  matrix $P$  such that $P^T M P = D$   is diagonal. Then the diagonal elements of $D$  give you the count  of positive, zero, negative eigenvalues of $M$  without needing to find the eigenvalues themselves,   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for the reference, I will read it in detail. I still have to understand both the method you link, and Robert's proposal, but it seems that they don't give me the bounds of $x$ directly but instead I need to construct them? I am still a bit unsure of how to construct the bounds from either method.

Comment: There is some personal choice  involved when constructing the matrix $P$  I mention.  The way I did it, the  three diagonal entries of my $D$  came out as $1, \; 2(x-1), \; \frac{1}{2}(1-x) . \; $ For all three to be non-negative you need $ x-1 \geq 0$ and $1-x \geq 0 .$   Thus $ x \geq 1$   and $1 \geq x.$

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for the clarification, though I have one doubt remaining. You mentioned on the first comment that $D$ gives you the count of positive, zero and negative eigenvalues of $M$. Wouldn't we want the third diagonal entry of $D$, $1/2(1-x)$ to be $0$? why do you consider the inequality $1-x\geq 0$ in this case?

Comment: I think you must talking about the maximum entropy idea  now. You began the question by stating the matrix would be PSD...  However, you then typed in a matrix that can only be PSD  when your $x=1.$  Perhaps you should give a more realistic example

Answer (score 3):

The determinant of your matrix is $-(x-1)^2$.  Since a positive semidefinite matrix must have nonnegative determinant, the only possible value is $x=1$.  You still need to check that the matrix is actually PSD when $x=1$.

More generally, a matrix is PSD iff all principal minors are nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am aware that the solution to this particular matrix is $x=1$ but I was wondering more about a general method.

Answer (score 2):

This matrix will fail to be positive definite except in the case that $x = 1$. One way to see this is to consider the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)
$$
\pmatrix{1 & x\\x & 1} - \pmatrix{1\\1}(1)^{-1}\pmatrix{1 & 1} = \pmatrix{0&x-1\\x-1&0}.
$$
This matrix will have determinant $-(x-1)^2$, which is negative except in the case that $x = 1$.

This method can be applied more generally whenever a [principal submatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Submatrix) of a positive semidefinite matrix is altered.

Answer (score 1):

A Hermitian (or real symmetric) matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are non-negative, see [PSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix).
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=values%20%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2Cx%7D%2C%7B1%2Cx%2C1%7D%7D) gives the eigenvalues of the considered matrix
$$\lambda_1=1-x, \;\lambda_{2,3}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+2\pm \sqrt{x^2+8}\right).$$
Clearly, $$\lambda_1\ge 0\iff x\le 1,$$
while $$\lambda_3\ge0\iff x+2 - \sqrt{x^2+8}\ge0 \iff x\ge 1.$$ This gives the unique value $x=1$ that makes the matrix PSD. It is easy to see that
also $\lambda_2\ge 0.$