# What is the relation between off-diagonal entries and the determinant of a SPSD matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, determinant, information-theory, entropy

I am interested in the differential entropy of a multivariate Gaussian distribution, $h(f)$. In particular, I want to know how does $h(f)$ change with changes in the off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix, $\Sigma$. As a reminder, $h(f)\propto \frac{1}{2}\text{det}(\Sigma)$.

We know $\Sigma$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, so that $\text{det}(\Sigma)\geq 0$.

For a $2\times 2$ matrix,
$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&c\\
c&d
\end{vmatrix}= ad-c^2
$. Implying that the lower the covariance between the two variables, the higher the entropy of the distribution (as we would expect, because if the variables have higher covariance, the distribution is "less random").

For a $3\times 3$ matrix the conclusion is less clear:
$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&d&e\\
d&b&f\\
e&f&c\\
\end{vmatrix}= a(bc-f^2)-d(dc-fe)+e(df-be)
$.

> Can we say anything about the relation between the off-diagonal elements of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and its determinant?

Comment: For any off-diagonal entry, increasing (or decreasing) that entry (while leaving all entries constant) by a sufficient amount will eventually cause the determinant to be zero. At that point, increasing the off-diagonal entry further will cause the matrix to stop being positive semidefinite..

Comment: More locally: [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) (along with the fact that $h(f) \propto k +  \log\det \Sigma,$ not just $\det \Sigma$) let's you figure out the derivative with respect to perturbing any one pair $\Sigma_{ij},\Sigma_{ji}$ as  $2(\Sigma^{-1})_{ij}.$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your answer. Do you have any intuition about the relations you pointed out and the entropy of the multivariate gaussian and such covariance matrix?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you for your answer. In the same way I asked Ben. Do you have any intuition about this derivative and the entropy of a multivariate gaussian with such covariance matrix?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I was working out the derivative as you did, but I get that the derivative of the $i-j$ entry on the covariance matrix is the inverse of the $j-i$ cofactor of the covariance matrix, and not 2 times the inverse of the entry itself. Could you please elaborate a bit on how you got to your result?

Comment: I think I was working out the derivative when you vary $\Sigma_{ij}$ and $\Sigma_{ji}$ together (to maintain symmetry of the covariance). And yes, you'd end up with $(\Sigma^{-1})_{ji} + (\Sigma^{-1})_{ij}$ but $\Sigma^{-1}$ is symmetric as well. Also, sorry, I missed your last comment. I think my intuition is the same as yours, increasing (absolute value of) correlation should decrease entropy, but more care is probably needed.

Comment: Actually even in your 3D case, there are complications: write $d = \sqrt{ab}\rho_{12}, e = \sqrt{ac}\rho_{31}, f = \sqrt{bc}\rho_{23}$, which is motivated since then the $\rho$s all live in the common space $[-1,1]$. Working out the derivative of $\det \Sigma$ with respect to $f$ (because the entropy is monotonic in this), we see that this is positive when $\rho_{31}\rho_{12} > \rho_{23}$. So certainly it's possible that increasing the correlations can increase the entropy, even when each entry is positive (e.g. take $\rho_{31} = \rho_{12} = 0.5, \rho_{23} = 0.2).$

Comment: Of course, if $|\rho_{23}| = 1,$ then the entropy becomes $-\infty$, so it's natural to guess that for large $\rho_{23} > 0,$ increasing it will reduce entropy. I don't think I have anything more illuminating to say though.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you very much! If you are interested, you could compile these comments into a unified answer and I'd be happy to accept it as such

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Interestingly, this seems to imply that if we have bounds on the possible values of the missing off-diagonal element (say using the methods in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4743500/610206), then the MAXENT choice would be an interior point. Though I am not absolutely certain of such statement.